# Calculate term of mortgage based on monthly payment value

Tags: compound-interest, mortgage-rate

Using the `PMT` formula in Excel, I can calculate the monthly payments based on the interest on the loan (e.g.2%), the principal value of the loan (e.g. £100,000), and the term of the loan (e.g. 25 years).

Is there an equivalent formula, to take the monthly payments, the principal and the percentage; and output the term for the loan?

In other words, could someone rearrange the equation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Monthly_amortized_loan_or_mortgage_payments for me, so that `n` is assigned instead of `c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [excel use the nper() formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nper-function-240535b5-6653-4d2d-bfcf-b6a38151d815?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60106&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us):

> Description
>
> Returns the number of periods for an investment based on periodic,
> constant payments and a constant interest rate. Syntax
>
> NPER(rate,pmt,pv,[fv],[type])
>
> For a more complete description of the arguments in NPER and for more
> information about annuity functions, see PV.
>
> The NPER function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> - Rate    Required. The interest rate per period.
> - Pmt    Required. The payment made each period; it cannot change over the life of the annuity. Typically, pmt contains principal and
>   interest but no other fees or taxes.
> - Pv    Required. The present value, or the lump-sum amount that a series of future payments is worth right now.
> - Fv    Optional. The future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after the last payment is made. If fv is omitted, it is assumed
>   to be 0 (the future value of a loan, for example, is 0).
> - Type    Optional. The number 0 or 1 and indicates when payments are due.

for your example:

```
 =PMT(2%/12,25*12,100000) or 423.85 per month
 =NPER(2%/12,423.85,-100000) or 300.0004 months
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the formula for the present value of an ordinary annuity:
[image]

the rearrangement is straightforward.  Unfortunately, this site does not welcome the input of mathematical formulas, so by verbal description

1. Divide both sides by C
2. Multiply both sides by i
3. Subtract 1 from both sides
4. Change the sign of both sides
5. Take logarithms of both sides
6. Divide both sides by log(1 + i)
7. Change the sign of both sides
   and we are left with:

n = - (log (1 - PV x i / C) / log(1 +i ))

In general, this will not lead to an integer solution.

Your options then would be to use the **closest** integer and adjust either the **last** payment, the **principal amount**, or the **regular payment**.

EDIT:  This site: https://brownmath.com/bsci/loan.htm#LoanNumber shows the formula, with different symbols, properly type-set

[image]